# messages going down leaving the scroll bar at its position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with my script as its not fulfilling the basic chat algorithm.

```
<script>
$ = jQuery;
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;
var scrolled=false;

function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
     }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#chatbox").show();
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
      if(!scrolled){
      $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight);
      scrolled=true;
      }
    }

  });

}

$(document).ready(function() {

 fetch_data();

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    setInterval(function() {
    fetch_chat();}, 500);
});



  $("#sub").click(function() {
    var text = $("#text").val();
    $.post('insert_chat.php', {
      id: currentID,
      msg: text
    }, function(data) {
      $("#messages").append(data);
      $("#text").val('');
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

I want to keep the scroll bar at the bottom until user want to scroll it up and the scroll bar should keep updated to bottom(to the last message) but thescroll bar remain at its position it was at first and the messages keeps on adding to bottom.
[image: heres the image explaing my query]